# Como saber se o elemento atual do iterador é o último em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iterator

Utilizando um `for` “clássico” para iterar sobre um array, posso saber se estou no último elemento pelo índice do array. Assim:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  const isLast = i === arr.length - 1;
  console.log(`${arr[i]} ${isLast ? 'é' : 'não é'} o último.`); 
}
```

Contudo, por ser uma abstração mais ampla, um iterador não necessariamente está associado a um índice (embora pode-se utilizar um contador para isso) e nem a um comprimento total. Ao contrário de arrays, que sempre têm um tamanho, um iterador pode gerar valores infinitamente.

Visto isso, existe algum meio que, garantidamente funcionando para *qualquer* iterador, informe se o elemento da iteração atual é o último?

Por exemplo, neste `for..of`, que consome um iterador criado a partir de um array:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (const element of arr) {
  // Como fazer isto?
  //console.log(`${arr[i]} ${isLast ? 'é' : 'não é'} o último.`);
}
```

Claro que em arrays isso se torna desnecessário, mas como não existe `length` e `i` para qualquer iterador, preciso de algo mais genérico.

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Usando `for (const [index, item] of iterator.entries())`  você terá o indice, você também pode obter o `length` como `const total = iterator.length - 1` e usar no item atual o `if (item.indexOf() === total) console.log('ultimo');`. Talvez você tenha em mente outro caminho, algo mais especifico, mas ando por fora.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o problema é que `entries` não é implementado por _qualquer_ iterador. Arrays, por exemplo, implementam via `Array.prototype.entries`, mas nem sempre é o caso. Ademais, nem todo iterador tem um `length` associado, então mesmo que todos implementassem `entries` (o que é factível com um contador), ainda sim não teríamos com o que comparar esse índice assumindo um iterador infinito. A pergunta usa array como exemplo, mas explicitamente pede por algo mais genérico.

Comment: @LuizFelipe estava lendo aqui mas não consegui imaginar um use case onde se precise saber se é o último elemento, tem um exemplo? Fiquei curioso, é apenas para ilustrar mais pergunta :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual, a ideia da pergunta veio de uma função que deve mostrar uma árvore no terminal. Os filhos de cada nó foram implementados com uma função geradora, e não um array, de modo que não poderia usar o `length`. Eu preciso saber se é o último para mudar o caractere do _pipe_. :) [Veja um exemplo de saída.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihLnf.png)

Comment: entendi, obrigado @LuizFelipe, um menu com multiplos níves por exemplo seria um bom exemplo prático disso :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual supondo que antes de processar o atual item do iterador você precisasse executar uma tarefa acaso seja o último item, então você pode checar, executar a tal tarefa extra e por fim seguir o processo normal em cima do item como fez nos processos anteriores. Um cenário hipotético, você tem um sistema de template HTML, precisa que no ultimo item colocar um elemento antes do ultimo item para evitar um possivel agrupamento ou quebra, então se você puder saber **previamente** que o item atual é ultimo pode inserir algum HTML na "frente" desse ultimo...

Comment: ... É claro que isso é só um exemplo hipotético, provavelmente no dia a dia você encontrar alguma necessidade sobre quando precisar saber **previamente**, para a maioria dos casos (não estou falando de templates HTML), você pode simplesmente executar um processo fora e após o loop, isso quando não precisa que seja algo prévio. @RicardoPontual

Comment: entendi @GuilhermeNascimento, e eu lembrei de um caso "clássico", por exemplo está montando uma lista concatenando coisas, os campos de um select por exemplo. Ao final colocamos vírgula, mas não queremos fazer isso caso seja o último elemento, é um outro exemplo de uso que me lembrei agora lendo os comentários de vocês

Comment: @RicardoPontual sim, em resumo é quando você precisa resolver algo previamente no ultimo item, antes processa-lo, para a maioria dos casos será dispensável, pois muita coisa pode se resolver de forma prática ou até de depois do loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução, baseada fortemente em princípios de *composição*, é utilizar uma função geradora para implementar um outro iterador. E, com isso, compor iteradores.

Esse novo iterador basicamente vai delegar a geração dos valores para o iterador original. A diferença é que o novo sempre estará “um passo à frente” do original, de modo a ser capaz de verificar se a iteração já acabou para o elemento atual.

Assim:

```
function* withLast(iterable) {
  const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  let curr = iterator.next();
  let next = iterator.next();
  while (!curr.done) {
    yield [next.done, curr.value];
    [curr, next] = [next, iterator.next()];
  }
}
```

Repare que, na primeira iteração do iterador retornado por essa geradora, chama-se `next` duas vezes. Para as próximas iterações, sempre chamo o `next` correspondente ao elemento da próxima iteração por ele gerada.

Essa implementação se baseia fortemente nos conceitos primitivos que formam os [protocolos de iteração](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) do JavaScript.

Para o exemplo da pergunta:

```js
function* withLast(iterable) {
  const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  let curr = iterator.next();
  let next = iterator.next();
  while (!curr.done) {
    yield [next.done, curr.value];
    [curr, next] = [next, iterator.next()];
  }
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (const [isLast, element] of withLast(arr)) {
  console.log(`${element} ${isLast ? 'é' : 'não é'} o último.`);
}
```

E como não estamos presos a ideias de índice atual ou comprimento total, é cabível utilizar essa técnica de composição para *qualquer* iterador. Exemplo:

```js
function* withLast(iterable) {
  const iterator = iterable[Symbol.iterator]();
  let curr = iterator.next();
  let next = iterator.next();
  while (!curr.done) {
    yield [next.done, curr.value];
    [curr, next] = [next, iterator.next()];
  }
}

// Função geradora que retorna um iterador "qualquer":
function* gen() {
  yield 'a';
  yield 'b';
  yield 'c';
}

for (const [isLast, element] of withLast(gen())) {
  console.log(`${element} ${isLast ? 'é' : 'não é'} o último.`);
}
```

Comment: +1 - Só lembrando que, conforme mencionado na pergunta, iteradores podem ser infinitos, então não seria possível fazer isso para "_qualquer_ iterador" (até porque, se é infinito, então por definição não tem último). Claro que isso não invalida a resposta, só comentei para "satisfazer" meu pedantismo :-)

Comment: Hehe :P Mas como assim, não seria possível, @hkotsubo? Essa implementação _é possível_ para um iterador infinito, de modo que _jamais_ retornará `true` indicando que é o último elemento, afinal, como você mesmo disse, não existe último.

Comment: É, pensando por esse lado, então funciona para todos os casos mesmo :-)

Comment: Estou achando um pouco confusa a nomenclatura. S.m.j. `const iterator = [1, 2, 3]` não é um *iterator*, mas um *iterable*, o *iterator* da solução é o `const it`.

Comment: Realmente, @VanderSantos, você está certo. Irei editar, muitíssimo obrigado.